# I need to create an image of Windows 7 domain PC and then put it on another PC (same make/model) and on to the same domain

Tags: windows-7, domain

under a different name, is this doable? I have some ideas on how to do this, but wanted to ask. Thank you

Comment: Doable but the image will have the same name and it must be changed before adding the cloned one to the domain.

Comment: The name is not a problem. The problem is the same station SID. It will cause the AD Workstation object interfere, making this object invalid.

Comment: This is what I was thinking also, Thanks for the suggestion, I will just need to remove the first PC from the domain, then take an image of it, join it back, clone the image to the new PC, change SID/name, and join it to a domain, right? Does this link of changing the sid make sense? https://www.wintips.org/how-to-change-windows-sid/

Comment: You should try to be a bit more specific when you ask. Anyway, take a look at "sysprep", although it cleans some identifiers, so I'm not sure if it will sign the computer out of the domain afterwards or not.

Comment: I just wanted to add to say what worked: 
-unjoin source PC from the domain
-clone it using Acronis boot CD
-join it back
-install cloned drive to a new PC (no network pluged in)
-run "sysprep", and rename the ne PC
-join the domain

this worked for me